# Are there any downsides to using AUROC curves in low event rate samples?

Tags: dataset, unbalanced-classes, roc

I was just asked to familiarize myself with some methods looking at comparing AUROC for a few predictive scores to predict outcomes. Issue is that I have a dataset of about 200 with <5% with the outcome of interest. Given this low event rate is there any issues I should be aware of (or corrections to apply if they exist) for this issue?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! [It seems that AUROC has the same meaning in the imbalanced setting as in the balanced setting.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/625405/247274) That you only have ten members of the minority category, however, strikes me as highly problematic.

Comment: Many pages on this site discuss the sample-size issue for binomial models, which is a big problem with your data. See [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/441581/28500), [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/162150/28500), other answers on those pages, and the links from them. To illustrate the problem, do random samples of size 200 with a 5% success rate and see how variable the estimates of a simple success rate can be. Then consider the additional problems introduced when you're trying to evaluate predictors of success.