# Logistic regression - Exp (B) = 0? and sig is 0.999 or 1?

Tags: regression, logistic, separation

I'm having an issue with binary logistic regression for a project I'm working on.

For some of the variables, I'm receiving a significance value of 0.999 and exp(B) of 0. Is this normal?[image]

Comment: It looks like what has happened is that for some combinations of your variables no events occurred. This has resulted in the model trying it's best to predict a probability of 0, but the standard errors have become extremely large as a consequence. Take a look at the answers to this question to see some more explanation.  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/254124

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: See also for some ideas https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/260885/binomial-glm-non-significant-difference-between-100-opposite-groups-of-observ/260911#260911