# Best functional form to describe a scatterplot with a z-shape appearance with noise

Tags: nonlinear-regression

What might be the general form of the equation can be fitted to the below scatter plot? The result should look like an smooth ***Z***

[image]

Comment: is there any reason why some observations are dots and other crosses? --otherwise, i would say a complementary log-log function (after appropriately re-scaling the vertical axis to get things in 0-1), because of the strong assymetry [you will find it in R in the VGAM library, function cloglog()]

Comment: the plot includes two time series, one showed by empty disks and the other by crosses. I prefer to keep the vertical axis in linear form and not to change it into logarithmic scale.

Comment: The hyperbolic tan (tanh) has a z-shape with bounds -1..1 for y. You might try this using appropriate shift and scaling of the x and y-values

Comment: @Gottfried Helms; sure but that's just still one form of log transform ( http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1444/how-should-i-transform-non-negative-data-including-zeros/1630#1630 )

Comment: This shape is called [sigmoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function).

Comment: @user603: true, but finding the keyword "tanh" helped me much some years ago when I had the same question; "log" has been a much too general (parent) class of transformations - I had just failed to see its possible relation to z-shaped curves/distributions and I remember, it has been an awful fiddling with the pressure of a timeline...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

then, you might want to try additive models for quantile regressions (some pics/explanation [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/quantreg/vignettes/rqss.pdf), and the $\verb+R+$ implementation [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/quantreg/index.html)). These  have various desirable properties:

1. They resemble classical scatter plot smoother but they are *truly* non parametric in the sense that they do not assume Gaussian distribution of the residuals (for instance you're data seems somehow bounded, and this type of model would reflect that --a bit in the same sense as in the difference between quantile regression and OLS)
2. They are robust to outliers on $y|X$, and judging by the plot, you seem to  have of those aplenty.