# How to sequence z-score creation and log transformation in an experiment with multiple groups and conditions?

Tags: scales, z-statistic

In a psycholinguistic task, participants listened to and viewed stimuli, and were asked to make acceptability judgements  on them:

- 4 conditions
- 4 groups
- Rating scale from 1-5

I have been advised to use z scores and log transformation (for R) on the ratings scores:

#### Questions:

- Should the ratings be computed into Z scores before log transformation?
- Should computation (whether z or log first) be done by group or for the whole data set?
- Should computation (whether z or log first) be done by condition or for the whole data set?

Comment: The construction of z-scores *guarantees* some will be negative.  You can't take their logarithms.  The answers to the remaining questions depend on what you intend to do with the transformed data.

Comment: @Carol I've assumed that condition is within-subjects and groups is between subjects. is this correct?

Comment: Thanks for the many comments. 
Yes - condition is within subject and groups is between subject.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any reason to log transform AFTER making z-scores; it COULD be right to log transform and then take z-scores of the logged data. I'm not as sure on the other questions, but my intuition would be to log transform everything, then take z-scores, then do the analysis. That way, a change of 1 in a variable is the same amount in every group.

Comment: Thanks, Peter. I have tried both ways now and see that log transform after z scores gives me many missing values in SPSS, as the z number used is a negative.

Comment: Oh yeah, I should have thought of that.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that you could want to do. The following discusses some plausible scenarios.

#### Comment on Log transforming z-scores

- In order to log transform z-scores, you would need to add a constant to the z-score, in order to ensure that the values of the z-score are all greater than zero. See [my answer to this question on log transforming z-scores](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16822/how-to-log-transform-z-scores/16826). It is unlikely that this is what you want to do.

#### Creating overall rating averaged across conditions

1. log transform all ratings
2. compute z-score for each condition, but use the mean and standard deviation of all groups combined but each condition separately.
3. get the mean of each condition z-score.

This would provide one way of looking at differences between groups where in some sense each condition is weighted equally in the composite.

#### z-scores to aid interpretation of group * condition effects

Alternatively, if you wanted to look at effect of condition, then I imagine the z-score would be purely a tool to make the metric of the dependent variable a little more interpretable. In that case the procedure might look like:

1. log transform all ratings
2. Compute z-score for all ratings using means and standard deviations of all groups combined and for all conditions combined.

Comment: Thanks again, Jeromy.

The data will be used for GLM mixed effect in R.

I think your last solution is probably the best, although I am not convinced that Z-scores should be computed across all ratings. 

If the z-scores represent a value against a particular population, shouldn't I split it by group, given that one group (eg adults) may perform differently than another (eg young children), and therefore represent a different population?