# How to preserve points near zero when taking logs?

Tags: data-transformation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How should I transform non-negative data including zeros?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1444/how-should-i-transform-non-negative-data-including-zeros)

I have a question:

> Suppose we have a data point $(0,10)$. We then convert to a log scale. Excel gets rid of this data point since the minimum x-value is $1$. How do we keep this data point?

**Edit.** Can't you change the x-coordinate to $1$? So instead we have $(1,10)$ instead of $(0,10)$. The rest of the values are not changed.

Comment: You can't take the log of 0, so you can't keep that data point if you want to take logs.

Comment: This Q will also be helpful for you: [How small a quantity should be added to x to avoid taking the log of zero](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30728/).

Answer (score 4):

The convention is to add a small constant to all values in a vector before taking the log, whether it's base-10 or base-e.  So you might use, e.g., log(x+1) or log(x+.001), depending on which would have the least effect given the range of values you're dealing with.

Comment: @ronaldo2: Can't you just change the x-coordinate to 1?