# How to handle data which contains 0 in a log transformation regression using R tool

Tags: r, regression, nonlinear-regression

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How should I transform non-negative data including zeros?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1444/how-should-i-transform-non-negative-data-including-zeros)

I want to perform log transformation regression in R tool but the problem is that I don't know how to handle situations when data contains 0 since log 0 is infinite... Please help..

Comment: Take a look here http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1444/how-should-i-transform-non-negative-data-including-zeros . But probably you should convert them to non-zero values somehow.

Comment: Well if i were you i'd try to find another way.
What phenomenon are you trying to describe? Is the log-transformation really needed?

Comment: There is no best method to handle such situation. However, you can use log(x+c) where c is a small number or log(x+x/2). Also, you can try Poisson, beta or gamma distribution as an alternative.