# How to perform boxcox transformation on data in R tool

Tags: r, data-transformation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How should I transform non-negative data including zeros?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1444/how-should-i-transform-non-negative-data-including-zeros)
>   [Error in boxcox.default(y ~ x) : response variable must be positive](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/47296/error-in-boxcox-defaulty-x-response-variable-must-be-positive)

I want to perform box cox transformation on data using R tool .If anybody can help me with examples or commands to show how it is done in R tool.
Thank you in advance.

My main problem is I want to take log of data but if data entries contain 0 then log 0 becomes infinite .To handle this situation I am searching for the past 3 days .I found one solution to use boxcox transformation..but again it is giving this error.

Comment: As stated, this question asks no more than a pointer to the on-line help for `boxcox`. If you provide more details (available data, research question, reason to apply a Box-Cox transformation), it might be of interest to the statistical community. Otherwise, it will be closed as off-topic (see our [FAQ](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq) for more information).

Comment: I have added the relevant information.

Comment: You may want to try reading these threads: [how should I transform non-negative data including zeros](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1444/), & [how small a quantity should be added to x to avoid taking the log of zero](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30728/).

Comment: So I do not see how this question differs from your other one: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/47296/930.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `boxcox` function (documentation [here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/MASS/html/boxcox.html)).

Comment: I have seen this link earlier..I am getting this "Error in boxcox.default(y ~ x) : response variable must be positive" error when I am using boxcox..

Comment: My main problem is I want to take log of data but if data entries contain 0 then log 0 becomes infinite .To handle this situation I am searching for the past 3 days .I found one solution to use boxcox transformation..but again it is giving this error.