# Natural logarithm transfomation and zeroes

Tags: data-transformation, stata, missing-data, logarithm

I am using Stata 13 to estimate a simple regression. Given a rather positive skew of a few of my covariates, I figured to ln-transform the variables. 
However, I have a substantial amount of zeroes in the covariates. Ln-transforming the variables thus leads to many missings.

I came across several ways of handling the issue:

1. Replacing zeroes to a small value (e.g. 0.00000001)
2. Nottreating the issue
3. Dummying the zeroes in a new variable

I do not like option 1 and 2. Replacing feels somewhat random and just wrong. Not treating the issue results in missing information. I thus prefer option 3. But it does not seem to work for me so far. Here is an example of what I do.

```
clear
clear matrix
set more off

sysuse nlsw88

hist tenure

gen ln_tenure=ln(tenure)

gen null_tenure = 1 if ln_tenure==. & tenure!=.


reg wage grade tenure south
reg wage grade ln_tenure south

reg wage grade ln_tenure null_tenure south
```

The nlsw88 example dataset provides us with 51 observation with `tenure=0`. Simply regressing `wage` on `grade` with `tenure` is hence based on 51 more observations compared to regressing `wage` on `grade` and `ln_tenure`.

To not miss out on the information at `tenure=0`, I created the dummy `null_tenure=1` for all `tenure=0`. Obviously, `null_tenure` gets omitted when introducing it to the regression.

I have two questions:

1. Does this way of handling missings created by ln-transforming data make sense?
2. If so, How can I circumvent the dummy to be omitted ?

/R

Comment: One common fallacy should be mentioned straight away. Using extremely small positive constants rather than zero, rather than being a very conservative change to the data, is a drastic change to the data. This is marginally easier to see with logs base 10: a constant $10^{-6}$ becomes $-6$ on log 10 scale, one $10^{-9}$ becomes $-9$ on log scale; in short, the smaller the constant, the bigger the negative outliers created and on log scale too!

Comment: Exactly! Merely replacing is not an option (allthough it seems to be regularly done).

Comment: My point was that this particular replacement is unsound, but as the cited thread indicates there are other replacements that preserve information.

Comment: @NickCox, thanks for the thread which if course is very close to what I am asking. In fact, it answers question (1) of this thread. Answering the more technical question (2) however remains troublesome for me. whuber suggested to generate a second variable that takes the value 1 if the ln-transformed variable was initally zero (see here http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/1795/77419)  - but how can I prevent the dummy variable of being omitted?

Comment: 1 if initially zero and 0 otherwise: what's the problem?

Comment: The dummy gets omitted.
  
`clear  

sysuse nlsw88  

gen ln_tenure=ln(tenure)  

gen null_tenure = 0  
 replace null_tenure=1 if tenure==0  

reg wage grade ln_tenure null_tenure`

Comment: The question now seems to ne that when you try to implement that procedure (in Stata?) it doesn't work for you. I suggest that is (a) difficult to answer without worked example and code and error report (b) off-topic here if you did that; Statalist is now the better forum for that. If you think @whuber's suggestion was incorrect in principle, then you should be raising that in the original thread.

Comment: Stata code is not universally intelligible or reproducible here! Please note my previous comment, which crossed with yours. Nevertheless your error is simple: you must replace the zeros in `tenure` with 1s before transformation by `ln()`. Ask on Statalist and I or others will expand.

Comment: Thanks! I cross-posted the question with a more technical focus in Statalist
http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1295600-how-to-create-a-dummy-that-indicates-original-zeroes-before-ln-transformation