# If my data is too skewed, and transformation does not help?

Tags: regression, data-transformation, skewness

For linear regression:

If the variable is right skewed, a log transformation of the data is suitable. If the variable is left skewed, square, cubic or higher powers is suitable.

Source: http://fmwww.bc.edu/repec/bocode/t/transint.html

For the independent variables:

I applied higher powers for my left skewed data, but they are still left skewed. What do I do? Do I just leave the data as it is when I run my linear regression? Well certainly, my AICs are better without the transformation.

When I got rid off the transformation, the linear regression results are the same as before with the transformation.

Comment: Does the skewness in data collected even matter in a linear regression?

Comment: Do you talk about response or predictor variables, or both?  Could you make the Q a little bit more specific by specifying your regression model (with equations), and telling us what the variables represent, that is, what they are supposed to measure?

Comment: Question updated...

Comment: You make some statements in your question. Are you quoting some source, or are you asserting these to be facts?

Comment: Yes, these are facts from my results...

Comment: It is interesting after applying a transformation for my left skewed independent variables, the linear regression coefficients and AIC did not change in R.

Comment: There is no assumption in regression that the predictor variables should have any specific distribution! So no need to transform.  See for instance http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1444/how-should-i-transform-non-negative-data-including-zeros/1452#1452  and serach this site, there are many good posts about transformations.

Comment: but what if I assume it in my linear model...for my study purposes?

Comment: Are variables skewed or regression residuals? The latter should be all that matters.

Comment: @Delta:  if you make such assumptions, then your model is not a stanfard linear model, and you shiold ecålain to us why you need those assuptions.