# Is it good practice to add 1 to 0 scores in log-normalization?

Tags: normalization, normality-assumption, lognormal-distribution

I am apply log-normalization to my non-normal data. However, when I apply log-normalization, the 0 values is converted into `inf`, which makes it impossible to apply some basic statistics on the data (e.g., correlation). Therefore, I add the score of 1 to all data values. However, I am afraid this is not a very valid approach. I wonder what is a common approach to deal with such situations.

Comment: The short answer is no.

Comment: @MichaelChernick thanks! But then what would be a better approach?

Comment: There is no need to normalize What is your model and what data do you have?

Comment: I have number of discussion post by each student. However some students have 40 posts whereas some others have 1 or 3 or 10 posts. I thought I should apply log-normalization to get a more normally distributed data. Am I wrong in doing so?

Comment: State what you are doing with the data that requires normality.  And note that if you have a zero it is not very logical to log that variable.

Comment: @FrankHarrell I am trying to calculate the correlation among two variables that can have any value (no range).

Comment: Perhaps you should ask instead "If one of my variables is skewed can I still use the Pearson product moment correlation?".

Comment: Please tell us your problem.  So far, after @MichaelChernick and FrankHarrell asked, you've given about half the problem.  My blog post [how to ask a statistics question)[http://www.statisticalanalysisconsulting.com/how-to-ask-a-statistics-question/) may help.

Comment: "Trying to apply some basic statistics" is a bad goal.  State your research question.

Comment: Another possible duplicate: [How should I transform non-negative data including zeros?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/1444/7290)

Comment: Sounds like a problem for Spearman or other rank correlation measure and be done with it.