# log transformation - negative values

Tags: time-series, logarithm

I am trying to log transform time series data of Inflation. However, there is one negative value. I have added the constant 1 to all my values and the log transformed.

```
loginfl <- log(infl_ts + 1)
```

Will this affect my analysis?

I am planning to tun predictions on this data.

Comment: You would usually log-transform your data `X` if you can safely assume that the underlying probability distribution of `Y = log(X)` is normal; you can then use a linear model with normally distributed residuals for a downstream modelling/prediction analysis. The fact that you have negative values suggests to me that this is not the case. Could you please clarify, what is the rationale/justification for log-transforming the data?

Comment: i am log transformig the data so i can interpret it as % increments

Comment: I would first model inflation directly (i.e. *not* log-transformed), then look at the distribution of residuals. You can always infer % changes from the model coefficients. If residuals are not (approximately) normally distributed, you might try a log transformation of the data; however the negative values suggest to me that your data is in fact *not* log-normal.

Comment: I am doing a time series analysis - checking for stationary, looking for granger causality, cointegration, predictions ... Why is the normality assumption of my residuals so crucial in this case? I thought i just need my residuals to be white noise ? I use the Ljung Box test to validate my Autoregressive Distributed Lag model

Comment: Most popular models for time series data analysis (AR(1), ARIMA, etc.) have some form of normality assumption. If your residuals are not (approximately) normal, the MLE process to estimate model parameters may not be reliable. Looking at the distribution of residuals is *always* a crucial step in assessing the quality/validity of your model.

Comment: PS. As far as I know, "white noise" usually means normally distributed.

Comment: Adding 1 will make your logarithms defined if and only if your negative value is more than -1. It is surprising that no one pointed out this out, unless everyone (including yourself) thought it too obvious to mention. Another problem is that the constant is bound to seem arbitrary and _ad hoc_. Note, most of all, that making the smallest value just bigger than zero after adding a constant  can create massive negative outliers. I'd stick with the original units as far as possible on these and other grounds.

Comment: The neglog transformation (suggested by @Carlos) is better than what you propose, but you'll perhaps have a harder job with comparing with other studies and with committee/reviewers etc.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=log+1+time-series for many more related posts.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider the log-plus-one transformation, as suggested on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/222237/146273) by @Firebug,

$Y = \text{sign}(x) \log(|x|+1)$

```
x <- sample(c(1,-1),size = 100,replace = T)*exp(runif(100, 10,20))
y <- sign(x)*log1p(abs(x))
```

Comment: The whole beast has also been called the neglog transformation. "log-plus-one" just sounds like what the OP is suggesting, but this is different.

Comment: A reference is Whittaker, J., J. Whitehead and M. Somers. 2005. The neglog transformation and quantile regression for the analysis of a large credit scoring database. _Applied Statistics_ 54: 863-878  FWIW, I don't find the name transparent, but I can't think of a much better one, and in any case it needs a really good name to justify muddying the waters with yet more terminology. I think I'd explain it as an extended logarithmic transformation, but even then it doesn't collapse to logarithm as a special case; it just is arbitrarily close for large $|x|$.