# Quantile Transformation with Gaussian Distribution - Sklearn Implementation

Tags: data-transformation, quantiles

This might be a vague question, but I'm wondering how is Scikit-Learn's [quantile transformation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/preprocessing/plot_all_scaling.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-preprocessing-plot-all-scaling-py) implemented?

I'm wondering how can a skewed dataset be transformed into a normal distribution like [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/preprocessing/plot_all_scaling.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-preprocessing-plot-all-scaling-py)?

Usually scikit-learn provides a link to the wiki, but not this transformation.

Can someone point me to the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, it appears to be described in a few different places, with no link to any papers.

The [class documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.QuantileTransformer.html) summarises the algorithm as follows:

> The transformation is applied on each feature independently. The
>   cumulative density function of a feature is used to project the
>   original values. Features values of new/unseen data that fall below or
>   above the fitted range will be mapped to the bounds of the output
>   distribution. Note that this transform is non-linear. It may distort
>   linear correlations between variables measured at the same scale but
>   renders variables measured at different scales more directly
>   comparable.

And the [user guide](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#preprocessing-transformer) adds some new information:

> However, by performing a rank transformation, it smooths out unusual
>   distributions and is less influenced by outliers than scaling methods.
>   It does, however, distort correlations and distances within and across
>   features.

Specifically, for a Normal transformation:

> Thus the median of the input becomes the mean of the output, centered
>   at 0. The normal output is clipped so that the input’s minimum and
>   maximum — corresponding to the 1e-7 and 1 - 1e-7 quantiles
>   respectively — do not become infinite under the transformation.

The [GitHub pull request](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/8363) for this estimator references [an older one](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/2176) that shows it was originally going to be named a "rank scaler".

In broader terms, [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2921808/) provides a good summary of the various ways that such "inverse normal transformations (INTs)" may be implemented:

> INTs are ways of transforming the sample distribution of a continuous
>   variable to make it appear more normally distributed. There are
>   several types of INTs. The first distinction we make is between
>   rank-based and non-rank-based INTs. Non-rank-based INTs entail
>   assuming a particular cumulative distribution function (CDF) for the
>   observed data, estimating the parameters of that distribution,
>   converting observed scores to estimated quantiles from the CDF, and
>   then converting these quantiles to standard normal deviates using the
>   inverse normal (or probit function). Such non-rank-based INTs are
>   usually referred to as copulas (Basrak et al. 2004; Li et al. 2006)
>   and will not be considered further. It is worth noting, however, that
>   the rank-based INTs can be expressed as a special case of the copula
>   method in which the empirical CDF is used instead of restricting the
>   CDF to some family of distributions. That is, every moment is in
>   effect estimated from the data and the quantiles become simple
>   functions of the ranks.
>
> Rank-based INTs involve a preliminary step of converting a variable to
>   ranks and can be further subdivided into two classes: those that
>   involve a stochastic element and those that are deterministic. We are
>   aware of only one INT that involves a stochastic element and this
>   approach has been referred to as the use of “random normal deviates”
>   (Conover 1980). One deterrent to this approach is that each
>   investigator applying the same method to the same dataset will obtain
>   a slightly different answer, which might be unsatisfying to some. This
>   approach has the theoretical advantage of avoiding the granularity in
>   the distribution of P values, an issue which often plagues many
>   nonparametric tests. Nevertheless, the stochastic nature of these INTs
>   seems to discourage researchers and they are rarely, if ever, used.
>
> Deterministic rank-based INTs can be classified into those that use
>   expected normal scores (Fisher and Yates 1938) versus those that use
>   back transformation of sample quantile (or fractional rank) to
>   approximate the expected normal scores. Using numerical integration,
>   Harter (1961) has provided the most complete table of expected normal
>   scores. INTs that involve back transformation of fractional ranks to
>   approximate the expected normal scores of Fisher and Yates (Maritz
>   1982) appear to be the most commonly used in genetic research and will
>   be the primary focus of attention. In back-transforming ranks, a
>   fractional offset is needed to avoid having the minimum and maximum
>   observations transformed to negative and positive infinity,
>   respectively. Perhaps the most commonly used rank-based INT
>   transformation entails creating a modified rank variable and then
>   computing a new transformed value of the phenotype for the ith
>   subject.

Looking at the [`QuantileTransformer` code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b46/sklearn/preprocessing/data.py#L2078), it looks like the very last item in the list: a deterministic rank-based INT that calculates a modified rank variable.

However, it's a relatively simple implementation:

1. calculate empirical ranks, using [`numpy.percentile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html)
2. modify the ranking through interpolation, using [`numpy.interp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html)
3. map to a Normal distribution by inverting the CDF, using [`scipy.stats.norm.ppf`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html#scipy.stats.norm)

taking care to deal with bounds at the extremities.

Representing as a *very* simplified mapping, i.e. ignoring the interpolation and bounding logic, it would just be $y_i = \Phi^{-1}(F(x_i))$, where $F$ and $\Phi$ represent the CDFs of an empirical and standard Normal distribution, respectively.

Comment: What an excellent, thorough answer. This was very helpful for me. Thank you for including the simplified mapping at the end for easier conceptualization.

Answer (score 1):

if a is qth qutantile, q in [0, 1]. Then after mapping, the value corresponding to a is norm.ppf(q). ppf is the inverse of cdf.

Comment: This approach is not well-based in statistical theory. First, we care about conditional distributions, not marginal distributions.  Second, we don't care much about distributions of predictors, only about the conditional distribution of Y given X.  Third, there are principled approaches to robust regression such as semiparametric models that do not need the transformation of Y to be specified.