# my error bars cross zero, is this ok?

Tags: standard-error

I have plotted the total consumption (g) of a solution by my experimental organisms. However, when I plotted the error bars (s.e.m) a few crossed zero (see image).

(1) is this correct/plausible? 
(2) How should I interpret this?

thanks in advance.

[![Standard-error bar plot][1]][1]

Comment: Your error bars appear to be symmetrical, so this is entirely plausible. What are these point estimates (histogram is not the right plot for mean / proportion) and how were the "error bars" estimated?

Comment: (1) Do you want to analyse this data using a model or are you only planning on doing descriptive statistics? (2) Is your consumption bound between zero and one (percentage) or can it be any positive number? In any case, I would simply visualize the data using [boxplots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_plot) instead since the arithmetic mean (and hence the standard error of the mean) isn't the best choice for your type of data.

Comment: @Stefan (1) I am only planning to do descriptive statistics. (2) I thought this might be an option, I'll go ahead and create a boxplot. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not able to see the image.  (Is it there?)  But also, I'm having trouble coming up with a toy data set that will exhibit this behavior.  (Can anyone offer one?)  Are you sure you haven't made a mathematical error?

Answer (score 1):

I assume the quantity you are looking at should never be less than zero. Thus, this indicates that with the limited amount of data you have your model is a bit problematic and predicts that values could be below zero. Potential ways of dealing with this could include transformation of the data for analysis. One obvious option is log-transformation (especially if you never observe an actual zero value). If you then back-transform the numbers in each group after analysis, you get a geometric mean (instead of the arithmetic mean) with CIs/error bars that would not overlap zero.

Comment: Thanks for the help! However, there is actual zero values within this data set. Could you suggest another type of transformation I could use?

Comment: Are these true zeros or just below some lowest measurable level?

Comment: These are true zeros

Comment: @TomOliver: [This thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1444/how-should-i-transform-non-negative-data-including-zeros) and the linked article by Hyndman discusses a few options.